# Elasticsearch: Replace entire document if it exists

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch provides the functionality to update/patch an existing document using the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html). If the document exists, new fields can be added to it and old ones removed. If the document does not exist, elasticsearch returns an error and nothing is changed (unless an upsert document is provided in the request).

My goal is to entirely replace an existing document with a brand new one (i.e. delete the existing one and index a new one in a single operation). I realise this can be done simply using the [Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html), but this operation will not return an error when the document does not exist. I only want the document to be replaced if it already exists.

Currently, our system sends a search request to retrieve the existing document, and, if it successfully retrieves the document, sends an index request to replace the document. If the search request returns empty (i.e. the document does not already exist), the system throws an exception and the index request is not sent. This is not a reliable method for replacing existing documents since the document may be altered or removed between the search request and the index request. Ideally, elasticsearch would handle both these requests atomically in a single operation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement that by using update_by_query API.
(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)

You can also find examples from the links.

or You can just use update api with script like this

```
POST hello/_update/12
{
  "script":{
    "source": """
      ctx._source = params.data
    """,
    "params": {
      "data": {
        "user": "kim",
        "message": "hi"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This request replace source data with given params.
And it returns `document_missing_exception` error if there is no docs with given id.

Comment: As far as I can see, the documentation you referenced does not mention replacing an entire document. Only adding or removing individual fields, like the _update API.

Comment: I just updated the answer. I think you can do that with update API using simple script.

Comment: The updated solution doesn't seem to allow more complex JSON such as 
`"data": {"test_field": "test_value", "test_field2": {"test_innerField1": "test_inner"}}`

Comment: @Rafe I just tried the complex JSON and it worked. Did you get any fail message?

Comment: The returned reason: `failed to parse field [test_field2] of type [text] in document with id '1234'. Preview of field's value: '{test_innerField1=test_inner}'`. This is the entire body of the request `{"script": {"source": "ctx._source = params.data","params": {"data": {"test_field": "test_value", "test_field2": {"test_innerField1": "test_inner"}}}}}` and ES version 7.11.1.

Comment: It seems to happen because the field is already mapped to `text` type. The same problem occurs when using the Index API.

Comment: Ah, I see. The existing mapping is causing the issue. Thanks for you help!